# Base 2 different Blazor pages on the same code behind

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a single Blazor page that needs to be rendered dramatically differently in different situations.  I'm currently using a very large "if" statement to decide between the two but it's very clumsy.  There is significant logic in the code behind that I do not want to copy/paste.  Is there a way to base 2 different UI pages on the same code behind?

I've tried having 2 different pages with code behind, then inheriting a base class with all the logic, like this.

```
public partial class MyPageHorizontal : MyPageLogic
{
}

public partial class MyPageVertical : MyPageLogic
{
}

public partial class MyPageLogic : ComponentBase
{
    //logic and properties go here
}
```

I get the error "Base class differs from declared in other parts"

Comment: Why don't you create a base class (direct for .razor backend) with 2 different children (separation)?

Comment: If you have Razor files associated with those "Pages" inspect the generated code behind to see what they inherit from - it sounds like a mismatch between base classes - but I've never seen that message in Blazor before, so I suspect you have simplified the problem? Inheriting a base component is absolutely supported.

Comment: @AliBorjian that's what I show in the code snippet.  It's giving the build error I mention

Comment: @MisterMagoo The Blazor pages descend from ComponentBase already.  That's why the code behind is a partial class and not a regular class.  You can see this if you make a code behind class descend from ComponentBase and you'll see a warning "Base type 'ComponentBase' is already specified in other parts".  If I try to make the code behind descend from my own base, it looks like multiple inheritance to the compiler.

Comment: Ok, here's an example - how does your implementation differ? https://blazorrepl.com/repl/GFkAkjas06Oj2zPF17

Comment: @MisterMagoo Thanks for that sample.  I can't explain why that works, but I created a sample project and put it on github.  I tried copying yours but am still getting the error.  https://github.com/bradirby/BlazorPageInheritance

Comment: In that repo  - you are still not telling the razor file to inherit from your base -

Comment: Nice!  that fixed it.  Thanks for the help.  If you want to post that as the answer i'll accept it, or I can do it if you're busy.

Comment: @MisterMagoo how do I inspect the generated code?

Comment: @pm100 read up on the property EmitCompilerGeneratedFiles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Razor files need to inherit from your custom Base, like this

```html
@inherits IndexBase
@page "/"
@page "/IndexHoriz"

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.  This page should render horizontally

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />
```

The Razor compiler will assume they inherit from ComponentBase otherwise.

Comment: I updated the repo with the working code: ithub.com/bradirby/BlazorPageInheritance